# Delete files from SDcard using my App doesn't affect until i reboot or unmount and mount the sd card?

Tags: android

I'm writing a application which enables user to delete specific directories via SMS command . everything is working fine.When i go to the android GALARY all my deleted images getting apper in my android galary all of em are very blurry . when i go through a file manager software like Astro my dir has got deleted as i expected.but images withing the dir can be still shown in galary.when i plug my device in to pc and the funny thing is i can still see the deleted dir but i can't open it.I think images says they all are very large of corrupted.funny thing is when i reboot my device or unmount and remount the sdcard deleted images are no longer shown. what is the reason for that how can i prevent showing corrupted images in galary.My code so far

```
public static void delete(File file)
        throws IOException{

        if(file.isDirectory()){

            //directory is empty, then delete it
            if(file.list().length==0)
            {

               file.delete();
               System.out.println("Directory is deleted : " 
                                                 + file.getAbsolutePath());

            }else{

               //list all the directory contents
               String files[] = file.list();

               for (String temp : files) {
                  //construct the file structure
                  File fileDelete = new File(file, temp);

                  //recursive delete
                 delete(fileDelete);
               }

               //check the directory again, if empty then delete it
               if(file.list().length==0){
                 file.delete();
                 System.out.println("Directory is deleted : " 
                                                  + file.getAbsolutePath());
               }
            }

        }else{
            //if file, then delete it
            file.delete();
            System.out.println("File is deleted : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete files in Android using it this way:

```
File file = new File(pathToFile);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Don't forget to add

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file!